# Derivative of random normal times indicator function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, random-variables, dirac-delta, characteristic-functions

I have to find $\frac{dE[f(X)]}{dX}$ where $f(X) = X1_{X>a}$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$ , $1_{X>a}$ is an indicator function taking value 1 if $X>a$ and $0$ otherwise, and $a$ is some constant. I have trouble understanding how to differentiate a random variable (standard normal in this case). On the top of it, an indicator function of random variable is involved.

My approach: Use simple chain rule first and get $\frac{dE[f(X)]}{dX} = E[X\delta_{X} + 1_{X>a}]$ where $\delta_{X}$ is the delta function. Is this in the right direction? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Derivative w.r.t. $X$ does not make sense. My guess  is it is supposed to be derivative w.r.t. $a$.

Comment: Thanks. If it is derivative w.r.t. a, then how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(f(X))=\int_a^{\infty} x \phi (x)dx$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal density. The derivative of this w.r.t. $a$ is $-a\phi(a)=-\frac a {\sqrt 2\pi} e^{-a^{2}/2}$.

Comment: What would be $E[X|I_{X>a}]$ then,  the conditional probability?

Comment: @Alex $E[X|X>a]=\frac {E[X1_{X>a}]} {P(X>a)}$

Comment: Yes I know that of course. I thought previously the formula you gave is for conditional probability, not joint. And that there's another one for conditional.

Comment: @Alex $\int_a^{\infty} x \phi (x)dx $ is the correct formula. For the coniditional probability it will be $\int_a^{\infty} x \phi (x)dx / \int_a^{\infty} \phi (x)dx $.